# jQuery validation plugin with grouped input elements by name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the plugin working correctly for half of my form, but I also have multiple form elements with the same name like so:

```
               <tr class="orderItems">
                  <td><input type="text" name="code[]" class="codeRowForm" value="" /></td>
                  <td>
                      <select class="selectProductOrders" name="selectProductOrders[]">
                         <option value="default" disabled selected>Select a product</option> 
                     </select>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="rsp[]" class="rsp" value="" /></td>
                  <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="trade[]" class="trade" value="" /></td>
                  <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="discount[]" class="discount" value="0" /></td>
                  <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="qty[]" class="qty" value="" /></td>
                  <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="cost[]" class="cost" value="" /></td>
                  <td class="deleteOrderRow"><a onclick="return false;" href="#"><img class="addRemoveOrderButton" src="img/deleteOrderRow.png" /></a></td>
              </tr>
```

This `<tr>` is repeated multiple times depending on how many order items the user decides to have in the form. So if the names are all the same (for example `name=code[]` ) in each row, how would I go about applying jQuery form validation using the plugin: [docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) ??

Thanks

Comment: That's why plugins are a pain in the ass.

Comment: Firstly, you're going to have to show your jQuery code.  Secondly, how can you expect it to function properly if all the names are exactly the same?  That's how the plugin keeps track of the fields.  Or is there a unique index inside the brackets of each name?  `name="code[2]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each `name` attribute is unique, e.g. `code[4]`, `code[9]`, etc., you get validation to work by enclosing the name with brackets in quotes.

[See documentation: "Fields with complex names (brackets, dots)"](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your other options,
        rules: {
            'code[1]': {
                // rules
            },
            'code[2]': {
                // rules
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/TKeEc/**

You could also assign rules based on the first part of the `name`.  Assigns the same rule to all fields containing `code` in the `name`, e.g. `code[4]`, `code[9]`, etc.

```
$('[name*="code"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        // other rules
        messages: {  // optional custom messages
            // custom messages
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/TKeEc/1/**

**Otherwise**, if you have multiple fields all containing the exact same `name` attribute, this plugin will not function.  You cannot reasonably expect any JavaScript validation to work if you can't target a particular `input` uniquely.  Broken:  http://jsfiddle.net/4ZV9D/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see what you mean, but was more hoping for a way to target multiple classes with the same name. I have found a way to do so which is by looping through classes after the validate has been initiated, which works fine. Thanks though, cleard a lot up for me