# Validation of fields with same name and class get "TypeError: e.validator.methods[o] is undefined"

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this HTML code:

```
<section id="variations_holder">
    <input type="text" name="field1" class="pprice" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" class="pprice" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</section>
```

And this is the code I'm using to handle validation:

```
$('#variations_holder input.pprice').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Debes introducir un precio de la variación",
            number: "El precio de la variación debe ser un valor numérico o decimal"
        }
    });
});
```

And it works, however when the HTML looks like this (notice input has the same name's):

```
<section id="variations_holder">
    <input type="text" name="field1" class="pprice" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field1" class="pprice" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</section>
```

The same code stop working and cause this error:

> TypeError: e.validator.methods[o] is undefined

How I can fix this issue?

This is derived from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252706/trigger-validation-on-form-with-multiple-sections-and-unknown-input-fields)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"... the HTML looks like this (notice **input has the same name's**):"*

```
<input type="text" name="field1" class="pprice" />
<input type="text" name="field1" class="pprice" />
```

> *"How I can fix this issue?"*

For the **fifth** time...

### You can **NOT** have multiple input elements with the same value for every `name` attribute.

**Because the plugin will NOT be able to keep track of the elements; there is no solution and no workaround for this specification.**

(*a collection or "group" of `checkbox` or `radio` elements is considered as "one data input", so they can share a `name` but only within the group representing this single piece of form data.*)

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"This is derived from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252706/trigger-validation-on-form-with-multiple-sections-and-unknown-input-fields)"*

Where in [my answer to that same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279061/594235), I said:

> 1. *"... **the jQuery Validate plugin requires that each input element contain a unique name attribute**. This is how the plugin keeps track of elements. ..."*

as well as in the very second comment [on the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19252706/594235), I said:

> 2. *"You cannot have multiple elements with same name. jQuery Validate requires that the name be unique."*

and in a comment [on my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279061/594235), I said:

> 3. *"**However**, each element **must** contain a unique name, no matter how the rules are created and applied."*

and in my last comment [on the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19252706/594235), I said:

> 4. *"... The jQuery Validate plugin needs unique names on data input elements because that's how the plugin keeps track of them internally.  There is no way around this requirement."*

---

Also see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19280015/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745248/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17643385/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16658340/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18022304/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15162231/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18963614/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816867/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18022304/594235
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905194/594235

Sources:

- [jQuery Validate Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:594235 [jquery-validate] unique name](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user:594235%20%5Bjquery-validate%5D%20unique%20name)

Comment: It's worth noting that radio button inputs *can* have the same name, as long as class rules are only applied to one of the inputs in the group. See [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405138/jquery-validate-radio-button-group-nesting-issue)

Comment: @amigolargo, I assume the reader already knows that a "grouping" of radios or checkboxes usually represents a ***single*** input point as far as form data is concerned.   **And the same constraint applies.  You cannot have two radio or checkbox _groups_ with the same `name`**.

Comment: It was just to clarify in case anyone read this post with the same problem I had been facing - how to apply class rules to radio button groups (only add the class to a single radio button within the group). This is not necessarily immediately apparent - no affront intended

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the solution in your case would be the following.

Plug-ins used:

- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="field1[]" class="pprice-group" />
<input type="text" name="field1[]" class="pprice-group" />
```

JS:

```
$("#form").validate({
    // Rules for form validation
    rules:
    {
        "field1[]":
        {
            require_from_group: [1, ".pprice-group"]
        }
    },

    // Messages for form validation
    messages:
    {
        "field1[]":
        {
            require_from_group: 'At least {0} field required'
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: The `require_from_group` rule only makes it *appear as if* your solution is working properly.  Otherwise, try using standard rules like `required`, `minlength`, etc. and the core issue becomes apparent:  http://jsfiddle.net/he21scmw/