# What's is the right way to handle validation using jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Since jQuery Validation plugin doesn't allow the validation of fields with same name then I wrote my own logic but it's not working. I have several fields in my form, those who validates trough the plugin and those who don't and I made this code:

```
$("#product_create").validate({
    rules: {
        "product[name]": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 50
        },
        "product[price]": {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        "product[quantity]": {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 1
        },
        "product[description]": {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "product[name]": {
            required: "El nombre del producto no se puede dejar vacío",
            minlength: "El nombre del producto no puede tener menos de 10 carácteres",
            maxlength: "El nombre del producto no puede tener más de 50 carácteres"
        },
        "product[price]": {
            required: "Debes introducir un precio",
            number: "El precio debe ser un valor numérico o decimal"
        },
        "product[quantity]": {
            required: "Debes introducir una cantidad",
            number: "La cantidad debe ser un número"
        },
        "product[description]": {
            required: "Debes introducir una descripción del producto"
        }
    }
});

// Validate price in variation
is_valid = $("#product_create").valid();

console.log(is_valid);

if (is_valid) {
    $('#variations_holder input.pprice').each(function() {
        pprice = $.trim(this.value);
        if (!pprice.length) {
            alert('El precio de la variación no se puede dejar vacio!!!');
            $(this).focus();
            $(this).addClass('error');
            is_valid = false;
        } else if (!/^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/.test(pprice)) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            is_valid = false;
        }
    });

    // Validate quantity in variation
    $('#variations_holder input.pqty').each(function() {
        pqty = $.trim(this.value);
        if (!pqty.length) {
            alert('La cantidad no se puede dejar vacia!!!');
            $(this).focus();
            $(this).addClass('error');
            is_valid = false;
        } else if (!/^[1-9]\d*$/.test(pqty)) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            is_valid = false;
        }
    });
}
```

What problems I'm having?

1. If `rules` fields (product[name], product[price], product[quantity], product[description]) does not validate then `is_valid` never takes `false`
2. Because the 1st issue then validation for `non rules`fields those with class `.pprice` and `.pqty` and then code goes trough this validation too and display alerts and I don't want that

What I need is:

- Validates fields with class `.pprice` and `.pqty` only if previous validation are right

Can any give me some tips or help?

**UPDATE**

Here is the rendered code:

```
<section style="" id="variations_holder">
    <div class="con_var header">
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">talla2</div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">color2</div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">color1</div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">UPC</div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">Precio</div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">Cantidad</div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">Foto</div>
    </div>
    <div class="con_var">
        <input value="Small" disabled="disabled" name="variation[content][]" style="width: 14.2857%;">
        <input value="Yellow" disabled="disabled" name="variation[content][]" style="width: 14.2857%;">
        <input value="Red" disabled="disabled" name="variation[content][]" style="width: 14.2857%;">
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">
            <label class="pupc">UPC:</label>
            <input type="text" class="pupc" name="variation[pupc][]">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">
            <label class="pprice">Precio:</label>
            <input type="text" class="pprice" name="variation[pprice][]">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">
            <label class="pqty">Cantidad:</label>
            <input type="text" class="pqty" name="variation[pqty][]">
        </div>
        <div class="galery" style="width: 14.2857%;"><span></span>
            <div class="cont ps-container" style="">
                <ul>
                    <li class="more"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="ps-scrollbar-x" style="left: 0px; bottom: 3px; width: 0px;"></div>
                <div class="ps-scrollbar-y" style="top: 0px; right: 12px; height: 0px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="con_var">
        <input value="Small" disabled="disabled" name="variation[content][]" style="width: 14.2857%;">
        <input value="Yellow" disabled="disabled" name="variation[content][]" style="width: 14.2857%;">
        <input value="Blue" disabled="disabled" name="variation[content][]" style="width: 14.2857%;">
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">
            <label class="pupc">UPC:</label>
            <input type="text" class="pupc" name="variation[pupc][]">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">
            <label class="pprice">Precio:</label>
            <input type="text" class="pprice" name="variation[pprice][]">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 14.2857%;">
            <label class="pqty">Cantidad:</label>
            <input type="text" class="pqty" name="variation[pqty][]">
        </div>
        <div class="galery" style="width: 14.2857%;"><span></span>
            <div class="cont ps-container" style="">
                <ul>
                    <li class="more"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="ps-scrollbar-x" style="left: 0px; bottom: 3px; width: 0px;"></div>
                <div class="ps-scrollbar-y" style="top: 0px; right: 12px; height: 0px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And this is how this code looks when is rendered:

[image]

Comment: [Are we still stuck on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19283520/594235)?  For the tenth time, if you want to use the jQuery Validate plugin, you'll need to give each field a unique `name`.  Your proposed workaround makes no sense... using the plugin for some fields and bypassing it for others.  If you really want help with this kind of frankenstein code, then you'll have to include enough code to make a demo... where is the HTML markup?  Then again, what's so difficult about assigning a _unique_ `name` to each?  <- That should really be what you're asking about.

Comment: @Sparky well lamentably I still stuck on this! I know that my proposal has no sense since I'm using the plugin for avoid this kind of manual validation but I can't find the right way to do it. What this means? As you may notice in others posts I'm using this as name `pprice[]` and why is that? That's because is more easy then to move into this element array from PHP side, if you know every other way to handle several fields then let me know and I'll take a look

Comment: Most people would use a unique index, `variation[content][1234]`, `variation[content][9999]`, etc.  Your server code should be able to handle the incoming array and assign the data to the corresponding record.